# Is it possible to render Adaptive Cards with Autocomplete Input Text Field in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I have the bot which working in MS Teams channel. I use it for creating some FTP groups and other stuff. The key problem, that now i have the large number of that groups and i wanna to filter them, before creating a new one. Is it possible to implement autocomplete  for input text-box? I'm trying to use input choice set as a drop down list, but is not good solution, because I have about 200-300  groups, and its very annoying to scroll them down. If you have any solutions, please share it!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible yet. The Adaptive Cards roadmap can be found [here](https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/tabs/5-roadmap).

What you are looking for is '[dynamic searchable select menu (like select2)](https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/15-dynamic-searchable-select-menu-like-select2), which is on the roadmap, but currently not planned.

Comment: That's really sad. Thank you Mick!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Mick said this feature was not implemented yet. But I hv some workaround to acheive this. We can convert the normal dropdown to the searchable dropdown using select2 jquery plugin.This helps the user to search the value in the dropdown without scrolling for a long time.

I hv attatched the images
1.before plugin how dropdown looks like
2. after plugin how it looks like
below which U can find the difference here

[image: before using select2 pluigin]

[image: after applied with plugin]

U can simply use jquery cdn and select2 cdn for getting these features.

Now inside the script tag u can write like this
$('select').select2();
So that all te dropdowns will changes to searchable/filterable dropdowns.
Refer this link https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage if u have any doubts on how to use this.
This worked for me.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to put that on the MS Teams Adaptive card? How do you put custom JS there?

Comment: No Kamil, if you are using bot-framework-webchat we cant do any frontend changes on MS Teams Adaptive cards as it doesnt supports any UI changes where as in react we can add custom JS.